# How to calculate weekly return for 3000 cryptocurrencies over 8 years... quickly?

Tags: r, portfolio

I am trying to come up with a way to create a portfolio building strategy that buys a portfolio of the coins that have had the best returns during the last week, and sells a portfolio of the coins that have had the worst returns during the last week.

I have a dataset with the closing prices for each week, with the columns "CoinName", "yyww", and "Close".

```
CoinName   yyww        Close
1       bitcoin 201401 8.549050e+02
2       bullion 201401 2.122034e+00
3   digitalcoin 201401 3.112048e-01
4      dogecoin 201401 2.841800e-04
5     earthcoin 201401 3.090447e-03
6   feathercoin 201401 4.227908e-01
7      freicoin 201401 8.091290e-02
8      goldcoin 201401 4.888827e-02
9  infinitecoin 201401 9.171350e-05
10       ixcoin 201401 1.215353e-01
```

AFAIK, I could try to transpose the "CoinName" into columns and loop a x-y/y function 1.2 million times, but I'm hoping there is a faster and more efficient way to do it.

Comment: Can you share expected output? Are you just looking to sort the coin types by closing price, and then select say the first and last few?

Comment: In `dplyr`, this would be something like `df %>% arrange(yyww) %>% group_by(CoinName) %>% mutate(wk_rtn = Close / lag(Close) - 1) %>% ungroup()` to get weekly returns, then you'd need to specify what threshold defines "best" and "worst." Top 10, those that are X% over/under avg, etc.

Comment: `dt1[, Returns := (Close - c(0, Close[-.N]))/c(0, Close[-.N]), by = .(CoinName, yyww)]` is a package `data.table` solution..

Comment: Someone please post an answer ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` solution.

```
library(data.table)

dt1 <- 'CoinName   yyww        Close
       bitcoin 201401 8.549050e+02
       bullion 201401 2.122034e+00
   digitalcoin 201401 3.112048e-01
      dogecoin 201401 2.841800e-04
     earthcoin 201401 3.090447e-03
   feathercoin 201401 4.227908e-01
      freicoin 201401 8.091290e-02
      goldcoin 201401 4.888827e-02
  infinitecoin 201401 9.171350e-05
       ixcoin 201401 1.215353e-01'
dt1 <- fread(text = dt1, header = TRUE)

dt1[, Returns := (Close - c(0, Close[-.N]))/c(0, Close[-.N]), by = .(CoinName, yyww)]
```

---

## Edit

The code below is more general purpose, it predicts a default value for the lagged close prices.
If the user wants code with the returns computations made by a function, that option is the code line that computes `Returns2`. This might be clearer code, it's up to the user to choose.

The data used in this example is created at the end of the post.

```r
returns <- function(x, default = NA_real_) {
  n <- length(x)
  (x - c(default, x[-n])) / c(default, x[-n])
}

dflt <- 0
dt1[, Returns := (Close - c(dflt, Close[-.N]))/c(dflt, Close[-.N]), by = CoinName]
dt1[, Returns2 := returns(Close, default = dflt), by = CoinName]
dt1
#>           CoinName   yyww         Close    Returns   Returns2
#>    1:      bitcoin 201401 854.905000000        Inf        Inf
#>    2:      bullion 201401   2.122034000        Inf        Inf
#>    3:  digitalcoin 201401   0.311204800        Inf        Inf
#>    4:     dogecoin 201401   0.000284180        Inf        Inf
#>    5:    earthcoin 201401   0.003090447        Inf        Inf
#>   ---                                                        
#> 4086:  feathercoin 202252   0.803213105 -0.5375175 -0.5375175
#> 4087:     freicoin 202252   0.190194680 -0.7134762 -0.7134762
#> 4088:     goldcoin 202252  -0.353006903 -1.1758555 -1.1758555
#> 4089: infinitecoin 202252   2.221135121  0.7175929  0.7175929
#> 4090:       ixcoin 202252   1.094813340 -0.6150876 -0.6150876
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Data creation code

```r
dt1 <- 'CoinName   yyww        Close
       bitcoin 201401 8.549050e+02
       bullion 201401 2.122034e+00
   digitalcoin 201401 3.112048e-01
      dogecoin 201401 2.841800e-04
     earthcoin 201401 3.090447e-03
   feathercoin 201401 4.227908e-01
      freicoin 201401 8.091290e-02
      goldcoin 201401 4.888827e-02
  infinitecoin 201401 9.171350e-05
       ixcoin 201401 1.215353e-01'
dt1 <- fread(text = dt1, header = TRUE)

set.seed(2022)
tmp <- lapply(1:51, \(d) {
  dt1$yyww <- dt1$yyww + d
  dt1$Close <- dt1$Close + rnorm(nrow(dt1), mean = 1)
  dt1
})
tmp <- do.call(rbind, tmp)
tmp <- lapply(1:8, \(y) {
  tmp$yyww <- tmp$yyww + 100 * y
  tmp$Close <- tmp$Close + rnorm(nrow(tmp))
  tmp
})
tmp <- do.call(rbind, tmp)
dt1 <- rbind(dt1, tmp)
dim(dt1)
#> [1] 4090    3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! I went for the dplyr answer since that was the one I got to work. Now to figure out how to build the quintile portfolios...

Comment: @OliverBrandtvig With your data size, `3000*8*52 == 1,248,000` there might a performance advantage in a `data.table` solution, though `dplyr` is also meant for speed. If you run this *many* times, profile both.